# Probablilites for wave function collapse

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, superposition

From what I understand, superposition is when two states exist in all of their possible forms simultaneously until the moment of wave function collapse, when they essentially reduce into a single state.

I'm having trouble demonstrating what a superposition state is using bra-ket notation (a simple example), and I don't really understand where the probabilities for collapse come from?

Comment: How about |Aup>|Bdown> + |Adown>|Bup>

Comment: There is no such thing as a collapse of a wave function. A wave function is a description of the quantum mechanical ensemble and it always stays the same. This means that an infinite number of repetitions of a quantum mechanical system can be in superposition, but the final state of any one individual measurement is (because of conservation laws) always determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A superposition of spin up and spin down for example can be represented in bra-ket notation as:

$\frac{1}{2}\mid\uparrow \rangle$ + $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\mid\downarrow\rangle$

This tells you that the probability of obtaining spin up during a measurement is $(\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{1}{4}$ and spin down is $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2 = \frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Okay I follow that; is there a general formula to show this? looking at this is it something like:

$C_o|\psi_1> + C_1|\psi_2>$ shows that the probability of $\psi_1$ occurring is $(C_o)^2$ and similar for the second state  ?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: Bear in mind that $C_0$ and $C_1$ can be complex and you need to multiply it by the complex conjugate, e.g $C_0C^*_0$

Comment: so is the half and root3 over 2 the amplitudes?

Comment: Its the probability amplitude of obtaining either eigenstate.